# Creating a semantic layer in QlikView

Tags: business-intelligence, qlikview

I am trying to figure out if there's a way to create a semantic layer, similar to what you can do with Catalogs in Cognos and Universe in SAP-Business Objects, in QlikView.

I am fairly certain that it is not something that you can do out of the box but I am wondering if there isn't a creative way to achieve the same through a combination of qvd and qvw files.

Comment: Could you explain what functionality Catalogs and Universe offer that you want to duplicate in QlikView? I know quite some things about QlikView but not about those other systems...

Answer (score 1):

You can effectively achieve this by creating a QVW which implements the data model and row level security, but does not contain any UI elements.  These "data model" QVW's (conceptually the same as a BO universe) can be reused in various QVW applications which implement the user interface.  The "data model" QVW can be loaded into the UI using a Binary load statement.

There are a few minor limitations with this approach in that you can only perform a single binary load statement in a given QVW, and that by taking this approach you are effectively increasing your IO (you need to write the data down once to the "data model" QVW, and then again into the UI QVW's n times).